# CMake don't reconise C include

Tags: c, cmake, include, clion

I think this question hasn't been asked and answered yet, I've searched but I might have missed the answer, I'm sorry of it's the case.
I have a project iwritten in C with the following file structure :

- CMakeLists.txt
- receiver.c
- receiver.h
- foler: connect

  - real_adress.c
  - real_adress.h

And the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(receiver)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99 -Wall  -Werror  -Wshadow  -Wextra  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -fstack-protector-all  -g -DDEBUG -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-omit-frame-pointer -lz")

set(SOURCE_FILES receiver.c receiver.h connect/real_address.c connect/real_address.h)

add_library(zlib ${SOURCE_FILES})

add_executable(receiver ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

My problem is the following: in real_adress.c and receiver.c I'm using external system system libs (such as fileno, getaddrinfo, etc) but, systematicaly, I got the same error when I try to compile, as if cmake was ignoring my #include:

For example in  receiver.c:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <netdb.h> 
#include "receiver.h"
...
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
...
```

and into receiver.h:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
...
```

Will send the following error when I try to run the makefile:

```
/home/pierre/ClionProjects/CustomProtocol/connect/real_address.c:17:22: erreur : ‘AI_PASSIVE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
                 ^
```

I don' understand why it think that AI_PASSIVE is undeclared, I've include all the necessary .h files.

Thanks in advance for all the answers, I know that my English is pretty awful and I apologize for that, It's not my native language.

PS: I think it has no importance because when I compile by hand I got the same errors, but I'm using CLion.

Comment: You show content of the file "receiver.c", but the error message refers to "connect/real_address.c".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

salut Pierre :-)

You are showing the includes in receiver.h, but the error is in real_address.c, maybe you don't have the correct includes in that file.

In any case, your cmakelists.txt is full of errors, for example never specify linker flags in CMAKE_C_FLAGS, cmake is not make.

You must take the time to learn cmake, not just randomly adding stuff hoping it will work.

I suggest https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/ and https://web.archive.org/web/20160729173019/https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/